# Ckeditor instanceReady is not working in 4.18.0 version

Tags: ckeditor, ready

Iam getting the ckeditor instance and used on method to use instanceReady and call method to setdata in ckeditor. But for some reason it is not working. Could someone please help.

Code:
Var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName];
editor.on('instanceReady',function(e){editor.setData(data);});

On ckeditor instanceReady, data has to be inserted to ckeditor as page has to display data on load.

I have tried with ready as well.it did not work.